# HTML display and MySQL data types

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have my website titles not breaking nicely when the lines are larger than the viewport, while the articles look great no matter the size of the screen. I run many tests and then I realized that the issue comes from the data types of these two sets of texts. In the MySQL database, titles are stored as varchars and articles as text. If I change the titles data type from varchar to text, then they look nice. Here is my question: is there an explanation why varchars strings behave (or render) differently from text strings? Thank you.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with data from sample table? Could you then make a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with the table structure and some sample data. Also, post the code for displaying the page as well as the css file. (Easiest way for that might be to make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))

Answer (score 0):

Post your code please, it would help to understand the situation.

It doesn't matter what's the data type by the way it might be your CSS or something else.